# Adding numbers into an alphanumeric value (Ex: "ABC" +1 = "ABD")

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

If what I asked in the title is not possible I will explain what I need and maybe there are other ways of approaching it.

I have a list containing either values or range of values separated by " - ", see below:

```
9565
9570
9626 - 9627
A015 - A020
A040 - A042
A070 - A072
A078 - A082
A095 - A097
GGAA - GGZZ
```

I want to create a macro that loops through the rows and "explode" the ranges into single values. Using the first **4** rows of my example the output would be:

```
9565
9570
9626
9627
A015
A016
A017
A018
A019
A020
...
```

Sadly they are not always numbers, so I can´t just put the range into a loop and add +1 to the previous value until the end of the loop.

Any Ideas?

Many thanks in advance and sorry for my English mistakes.

Comment: BTW, if there are other solutions without VBA I am open to it, just bear in mind that I need this at work, where I do not have many system admin privileges, so I can´t for instance install external applications.

Comment: can we assume that all characters are upper case?

Comment: can we assume that all values are always 4 characters long?

Comment: I won't add this as an answer as the highest letters you could have would be _XFC+1_ and it doesn't deal with numbers at all - it's just based off the "ABC+1 = ABD" in the title.  With your letter in `A1` and the number in `B1` this formula will calculate the Excel column and add the required number of columns to it: `=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT($A$1 & 1))+$B$1,2),FIND("$",ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT($A$1 & 1))+$B$1,2))-1)`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Or `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(CELL("address", OFFSET(INDIRECT(A1 & "1"), 0, 1)), 2, 99), "$1", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need this at some point - it returns the next text character in sequence, wrapping at Z. It assumes upper case only, and I haven't bothered handling edge cases

```
Public Function NextChar(s As String) As String
Dim x As Long
Dim answer As String
Dim flag As Boolean
x = Asc(Right(s, 1))
Select Case x
    Case 65 To 89 'A to Y
        x = x + 1
    Case 90 'wrap at Z
        x = 65
        flag = True
    Case Else '?

End Select
Select Case Len(s)
    Case 1
        If flag Then
            answer = "A" & Chr$(x)
        Else
            answer = Chr$(x)
        End If
    Case 2
        If flag Then
            answer = NextChar(Left(s, 1)) & Chr$(x)
        Else
            answer = Left(s, 1) & Chr$(x)
        End If
    Case Else
    '???
End Select
NextChar = answer

End Function
```

Comment: Extend it to `Case 65 To 89, 48 To 56 'A to Y, 0-8` and `Case 90, 57 'wrap at Z and 9` and it will even accept numbers like `A1 › A2` and `A9 › BA`

Answer (score 0):

It took me the whole day but I actually managed to do it!

Thanks @Harassed Dad ! I've adapted your code and the result looks like this:

**Function:**

```
Function WF_NEXT_CHAR(s As String) As String

    Dim ASCII   As Byte
    Dim i       As Integer

    s = UCase(s)
    ASCII = Asc(Right(s, 1))

    If s = String(Len(s), "Z") Then
        WF_NEXT_CHAR = "#"
            Else
        Select Case ASCII
            Case 57                     'Wrap Number at 9
                ASCII = 65
            Case 48 To 56, 65 To 89     '0 to 8 and A to Y
                ASCII = ASCII + 1
            Case 90                     'Wrap Char at Z
                ASCII = 49
                For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
                    If Mid(s, i, 1) = "Z" Then
                        WF_NEXT_CHAR = Left(s, i - 1) & "0" & Right(WF_NEXT_CHAR, Len(s) - i)
                            Else
                        WF_NEXT_CHAR = Left(s, i - 1) & WF_NEXT_CHAR(Mid(s, i, 1)) & Right(WF_NEXT_CHAR, Len(s) - i)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
        End Select
        If Len(s) = 1 Then WF_NEXT_CHAR = Chr(ASCII)
        If WF_NEXT_CHAR = "" Then WF_NEXT_CHAR = Left(s, Len(s) - 1) & Chr(ASCII)
    End If

End Function
```

**Sub (it assumes the ranges are in the column "A"):**

```
Sub UHUUUUL_xD()

Const Del   As String = " - "
Dim r       As Long
Dim Rng     As Variant
Dim i       As String

For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, Cells(r, 1), Del) > 0 Then
        Rng = Split(Cells(r, 1), Del)
        Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2) = IIf(IsNumeric(Rng(0)), "'", "") & Rng(0)
        While i <> "#" And i <> Rng(1)
            i = WF_NEXT_CHAR(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2) = i
        Wend
    End If
Next

End Sub
```